# Scorms hide to show moodle

Tags: database, moodle

I've created all courses in moodle and I've uploaded scorms in hidden status. 
How do I do to show all scorms from database?

Thanks!

Edit: I want do it in database, because i want do a massive update

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the list of Scorm-type activities in the database, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_scorm;
```